# Python crash at updating image on a Label

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, opencv, tkinter, tcl

I have a OpenCV image processing program that uses Tkinter in Python.I got a webcam feed and update the frames in to Tkinter Label.

Image processing is done in separate module.It outputs the frame of web cam to support module variable.

```
import Support

Support.frame=img #img is the processed web cam frame
```

Support module frame gets by the Tkinter class and display it.

```
def updateImage(self):
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(Support.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    self.lblFrame.imgtk = imgtk
    self.lblFrame.configure(image=imgtk)
    self.lblFrame.after(10, self.updateImage)
```

Above two loops handled by two thread.

Unfortunately, My program is crashed sometime. System gives following error details.

> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>
> Application Name: python.exe
>
> Application Version:  0.0.0.0
>
> Application Timestamp:   5193f37d
>
> Fault Module Name:   tcl85.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:    8.5.2.2
>
> Fault Module Timestamp:  4c790429
>
> Exception Code:  c0000005
>
> Exception Offset:    00098011
>
> OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>
> Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional Information 1:    0a9e
>
> Additional Information 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Additional Information 3:    0a9e
>
> Additional Information 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy >statement offline:
>    C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

This error has

> Fault Module Name: tcl85.dll

So, As I think this is a Tkinter error.

I'm using Python 2.7.5/OpenCV3.1

Comment: You can't modify a label in one thread if the label widget was created in a different thread. Is the code that updates the label in the same thread that created the label?

Comment: yes...I have only one thread for creating and updating the label.
I used `after`

Comment: That crash info is almost entirely useless, except for telling us that you're using an old release of Tcl 8.5. However it is _critical_ that you only use Tcl and Tk from one thread; the bridging code from Python doesn't work from multiple threads at all. (Tcl and Tk can use multiple threads internally just fine, but they use an utterly different threading model to Python. They don't mix at all.)

Comment: I have stuck in this problem.Please suggest the best way to update my Label.